# Image has no zoom effect with Fancy Zoom (jQuery Plugin)

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins, razor, webmatrix

I'm having problems using the jQuery Fancy Zoom plugn.

In my page I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<a href="ProjectImage?ID=@img.ID&Full=true">
    <img class="content-image zoom" alt="@img.Name" src="ProjectImage?ID=@img.ID"/>
</a>
```

On page ProjectImage have:

```
@{
    if (Request["ID"].IsInt())
    {
        var imgID = Request["ID"].AsInt();
        var full = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["Full"]) && Request["Full"].IsBool() && Request["Full"].AsBool());

        //Data
        var db = Database.Open("AMSDArquiteturaConnectionString");
        var image = db.QuerySingle("select * from Images where [ID] = @0", imgID);

        if (image.MimeType.StartsWith("image"))
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + image.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + image.Name);
        }

        Response.ContentType = image.MimeType;
        if (full)
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])image.ImageFull);   
        }
        else
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])image.File);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the same, the low image of the database once the user clicks on the image to show larger picture.
The problem is that this way the plugin does not work.

It simply displays the image in actual size on your browser and loads the whole page again.

If I put an image, it works normally.

I'm getting stuck. Thanks for the help.

Here are a few links from the plugin I used:

http://www.hardleers.org/multimedialab/js/demo.html
http://static.railstips.org/orderedlist/demos/fancy-zoom-jquery/
http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jquery-fancyzoom/

This is the javascript I use to configure the plugin

```
//Set Zoom                 
$.fn.fancyzoom.defaultsOptions.imgDir='../Images/';
$('.project-imagepreview a').fancyzoom({Speed:400, scaleImg: false, closeOnClick: true});
$('img.zoom').fancyzoom();
```

Comment: Does the code get the image from a database then, or load it after the page has finished loading? Can the Fancy Zoom code be initialized after the image has been loaded into the page?

Comment: <img id> instead of <img class> ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Javascript's 3rd line should be `$('img.fanzyzoom').fancyzoom();` as given in the references.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when zoom out the image, It show me picture with alot of meanless symbols.
 can show up my image, but plugin can not zoom it. I had tried with fancyboxm lightbox, thickbox.... 
plugin still work fine if I replace url: web/images?id=..... with web/images/somepicture.png